# React parent component update when child component alters database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a parent component which is a list of foods,the list of foods is received by a fetch request to my api that queries my mongodb databse.

Each food item is held inside a div which is a child component and inside each div is another child component a delete button. when the delete button is pressed it deletes that food item from my mongodb database. At the moment the parent component does not update automatically when an item is deleted from the database, I have to refresh the page so it makes another fetch request and gets the new data back.

How can I make it so it automatically updates when the data in my database changes.

Sorry for the wording, im not exactly sure how to ask this question. Thanks for your help.

this is the top component, makes a fetch request when the component is mounting

```
componentWillMount(){
    console.log('lol')
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/getDiet')
    .then((res)=>{
      return res.json()
    })
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log(data)
      var totalsObject = this.getUserTotal(data.diet)
      this.setState({
        dietArray: data.diet,
        ready:true,
        userTotals:{
          calories: totalsObject.calorie,
          protein: totalsObject.protein,
          carbohydrates: totalsObject.carbohydrates,
          fat: totalsObject.fat,
          sugar: totalsObject.sugar
        }
      })
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div className="user-diet-container">



        {this.state.ready ?
          <div className="diet-list-container">
          <h1>Your Diet</h1>
          <div className="user-totals">
            <h2>Diet Totals</h2>
              <ul>
                <li>Calories:{this.state.userTotals.calories}g</li>
                <li>Protein:{this.state.userTotals.protein}g</li>
                <li>Carbohydrates:{this.state.userTotals.carbohydrates}g</li>
                <li>Fat:{this.state.userTotals.fat}g</li>
                <li>Sugar:{this.state.userTotals.sugar}g</li>

              </ul>

          </div>

            {this.state.dietArray.map(function(item,i){
              return(

            <div key ={i}>
              <DietParcel values={item} id={i}/>
            </div>
            )
          },this)}
            </div>

          : <h1>here is your diet</h1>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

inside that component is a child component that gets created x amount of times, depending on the amount of food items returned from the orginal fetch request

```
    class DietParcel extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
          id: "component" + this.props.id,

        }
      }

      something(){
        console.log("lol")
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div  className="diet-item" ref={this.state.id}>
           {this.props.values.name}<br/>
          Calories:{this.props.values.calorire}<br/>
          Portion: {this.props.values.portion}<br/>
          <h3>Nutritional Information</h3>

          <ul>
            <li>Protein:{this.props.values.nutrition[0].protein}g</li>
            <li>Carbohydrates:{this.props.values.nutrition[1].carbs}g</li>
            <li>Fat:{this.props.values.nutrition[2].fat}g</li>
            <li>Sugar:{this.props.values.nutrition[3].sugar}g</li>

           </ul>
           <DeleteButton onClick={this.something.bind(this)} values={ this.props.values} component={this}/>
        </div>

        )

      }
    }
    export default DietParcel;
```

and lastly is the delete button which is is a child of the DietParcel component, when clicked it deletes that specific item from the database.

```
class DeleteButton extends Component{

  componentDidMount(){
  }
  deleteComponent(){


  }
  deleteItem(){
    myDietApi.removeSingleItem({id:this.props.values._id})
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <button className="DeleteButton" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}>x</button>
    )
  }
}
export default DeleteButton;
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: ok i figured it was more of a question that had to do with the logic of react, my apologies. ill put it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your description (*without any code sample*), I guess your application is structured like the following:

```
<FoodList>
  <FoodItem>
    <DeleteButton />
  </FoodItem>
  <FoodItem>
    <DeleteButton />
  </FoodItem>
  <FoodItem>
    <DeleteButton />
  </FoodItem>
</FoodList>
```

Also, I'm assuming that you are mapping an array of foods in `FoodList` (sort of a `state` prop) so then you can render each `FoodItem` along side its children.

My suggestion is to keep this *database fetching*  and *food deletion* inside `FoodList` only. Whenever you want to delete a food, `DeleteButton` sends food `id`, `index` or any identifier you might have to `FoodItem` which consequently propagates it to `FoodList`.

That being said, I'd remove the item as:

```
deleteFood(foodId) {
  // send request to delete food from your DB
  ...

  // remove food with foodId from state
  const index = this.state.foods.findIndex(food => food.id === foodId)

  this.state({
    foods: [
      ...this.state.foods.slice(0, index), // gets every food before
      ...this.state.foods.slice(index + 1) // gets every food after
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: okay i didnt know you could send information back up, how would I do that?also i added my code

Comment: You can propagate information up via props. For example: set `onClick` prop in `DeleteButton`.

Comment: okay so the onclick function would be a function that is created in the parent component and then passed as a prop? Out of curiosity would redux allow me to avoid this, i just started reading about it.

Comment: Definitely redux is going to help you :)